# Bootstrap Hover Horizontal Subnav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a menu with dropdown options with a horizontal subnav, and I want to have the subnav be revealed upon hover instead of click, but I'm having trouble doing so. The person I'm making the site for has requested that I don't use tabs or pills and to maintain this look and the current functionality.

I've tried looking at other guides on how to have the dropdown work on hover, but they were all for vertical subnav, and I tried getting them to work with a horizontal subnav but I still couldn't do so.

This is less important, but how would I go about reducing the clickable area of the dropdown menu so that you must click on the words, but still maintain the spacing of the menu. Also is there a way to fix the animation so that when I switch directly from Dropdown 1 to Dropdown 2 or vice versa, the original menu doesn't get pushed down then disappear? If worst comes to worst I'll just disable the animation, but I figured I would ask to see if there was a solution.

Here's a Bootply link to my code: http://www.bootply.com/zP99qlIYPP

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet here.

Comment: I posted Bootply link to the code snippet.

I'm also not being paid for this at all. This is just something I'm doing to help out a friend while learning HTML and CSS for my own benefit. We're both completely broke college students deep in debt and definitely aren't in any financial position to hire anyone.

Comment: I would love to be able to pay someone to help me with this, but as it stands I occasionally have trouble paying for my next meal, so hiring a CSS specialist isn't an option for me. Sorry if I made it seem as if I was being paid in my initial post. If possible I would still love to receive some help for this. I'm really struggling with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it means a lot to me. I'm very sorry for the initial misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do.

```js
$('#topmenu').parent().css({'position': 'relative'});
$('#topmenu .dropdown').hover(
    function () {
        hoverMe($(this));
    },
    function () {
        hoverMeNot($(this));
    }
);
function hoverMe(el) {
    var target = el.find('a').eq(0).attr('data-target');
    el.append($(target).addClass('out'));
}

function hoverMeNot(el) {
    var target = el.find('a').eq(0).attr('data-target');
    el.css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
    if ($(target).parent().find(target + ":hover").length > 0) {
        $(target).bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            hoverMeNot(el);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(target).appendTo($('#submenu')).removeClass('out');
        el.css({'pointer-events': 'auto'});
    }
}
```

```css
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #969590;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    min-height: 32px !important
}

.navbar-xs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav > li.dropdown:hover {
    position: static;
    overflow: visible;
}

.dropdown .nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: calc(100% - 1px);
    z-index: 2;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .collapse.out {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar-xs" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test1">Dropdown 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test2">Dropdown 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" id="submenu">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="test1">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Bar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Oranges</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="test2">
            <li><a href="#" id="">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">World</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="">Experimenting</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```